# Python: Best way to access variable from within a class instance?

Tags: python, oop, class, variables

I've got a class named **Player** and there will be 200-300 instances of this class. There is a function within this class called **Move** and this function requires knowledge of the map.

I also have a class named **Map** with 1-2 instances. What is the best way to feed an instance of **Map** into the **Player** instances?

I just ask because if i feed it to the instance upon Player **init** so I can access the instance via self.map - won't that be creating hundreds of copies of the Map instance (one for each instance of Player)?

For all I know this could be the standard way of doing it but I have a nagging feeling that this isn't proper.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you pass the `Map` to the `Player` at init this just passes a **reference**, not a copy.  You will not create redundant instances of `Map` this way, and it's the best way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing in Python is ever implicitly copied.  Whenever you do `x = y`, whether that's a function call or a variable/element/attribute assignment, `x` and `y` afterwards refer to the same object.

I see two pitfalls with your plan, though:

- Would the map also know about the players?  If so, you'll have a lot of circular references on your hands.  Just pass the map to `move()`, instead.
- It seems more appropriate to have the map itself, or some other rich "game logic" class, handle the actual movement.  (I'm not a game dev, though; my gut instinct is just that a thing on a map shouldn't reach outside of itself and move itself around.)

Comment: The thing on the map can ask or tell the map to move it.